# Identify shrub with red berries in UK

Tags: identification, trees, shrubs

Could you tell me what is the name of this plant?

Found in the park in London at the end of May.

Red berries on shrub with saw-toothed leaves.

[image]

Comment: I am looking up Viburnum...like maybe plicatum.

Comment: What we need, if you can provide it, is a photo showing a leaf or three very clearly, or a branch with whole leaves on it, and preferably one showing the whole plant for growth habit - I'd say a Viburnum variety, but there are lots and lots of those, not all with ovoid berries, but many with

Comment: Can you show us a fruit sliced open? Is it red inside? How many seeds per fruit? If one seed, is it elongated?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a picture of [berries and leaves of V. plicatum](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/51/55/fe/5155fe8ac67227ad31d65dd3667cbc8a.jpg).
Here's another picture, [Viburnum plicatum Mariesii Viburnum](https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=AwrTcc6nZDxZgBUAlKQnnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTByNWU4cGh1BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzYw--?p=Viburnum%20Mariesii%20Berries&fr=yhs-mozilla-002&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002#id=12&iurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thegardenerseden.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F08%2FViburnum-plicatum-var.-tomentosum-Shasta-Fruits-%E2%93%92-michaela-medina-thegardenerseden.com_.jpg&action=click).  See what you think!  I'll be blown away if I am wrong!

Comment: Not too convinced. The berries should be standing up in a circle, like the flowers before and the leaves seem not "grooved" enough.

Comment: I love Viburnum mariesii.  I know it well.  It was the first thing that popped up in my mind, and of course that is always fun but makes me very very skeptical.  Did you go look at the pictures? The elongated berries?  The grooves?  I always could be wrong, but sometimes I have to respect the info my little old brain remembers even though my filing system is really bad.  Hey, I am wrong at least 50% of the time but that gives others ideas to test and try different routes?  Berries are too heavy to stand up straight like the umbel?  the flowers?

Comment: It might well be what you suggest, but Stephie makes a good point, the berries are usually held in a hoop like arrangement - also the leaves, what we can see of them, seem quite long to be plicatum...

Comment: Sure look as if they could be in an upright...umbel?  Maybe too much water, shade just got run over by a horse?  Grins.  The structure is there and we all know that I am wrong as much as right.  I love Viburnum, especially snow ball and mariesii.  I owned 10 V. opulus, mature small trees.  A grove of them at the home I first purchased.  One day, came home to find them all hacked off at the ground.  Mariesii is one of my most planted large shrubs for natural areas.  We'll see!  Very interesting for all of us!

Comment: I just know that plants can get quite messed up but I also know there might be another Viburnum that matches.  I would have liked to see the entire shrub and more pictures.  We'll see...I'll learn...sigh!!

Comment: This is wrong answer. Leaves are clearly different from what you propose, more like prunus of some king.

Comment: Hey @J.Chomel  Can't believe this has no answer as yet.  Yet my answer is wrong?  Sigh.  What was wrong with Manchurian Viburnum?  That looked very strong...micro environments easily change leaf color and serration...a little bit.  Without giving a better answer, please explain how you KNOW an answer is wrong without just saying, 'this is wrong'?  I am wrong LOTS.  I like the Manchurian Viburnum ID.

Comment: I deleted my answer (manchurian viburnum) since it just flowers in may, so can't have such berries in that season.

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm very torn- I may be able to make a better decision between the two IF you had a picture of the leaf straight on or looking down on to the leaf as the ones in the pic are slightly curled. I've posted pics below of two plants that it most similarly resembles the first few are of dog rose hips and the second few are of black Hawthorne or crateagus douglasii. I've attached webbed searched images with the most similarity to the pic you posted. When I blew up your pic I saw Thorne's. Another reason I've chosen these 2. Leaning more towards rose hips after second, third and fourth-guessing myself.

Dog rose hips plant and berries

[image: dog rose hips]

[image: dog rose hips2]

[image: Berries of dog rose hips]

Black Hawthorne, pic one is of one in the UK.

[image: Black Hawthorne]

[image: black Hawthorne]

Hope this helps you or helps to restart the conversation to get you the answer your looking for.

Comment: Nice guess, however, there is a big problem: "It is in flower in May, and the seeds ripen in September." (from www.pfaf.org/user/plant.aspx?LatinName=Crataegus+douglasii) And OP says the picture is taken in May.

Answer (score 2):

I found this image of a [pin cherries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_pensylvanica):
[image: pin cherries] 
[from here](http://www.gettystewart.com/red-berries-edible-or-not-edible/), whose leaves have strong resemblance with the one of the original question.

> *Pin cherries are not commonly planted in backyards, but they can be found across the prairies in parks, along river banks and in other undisturbed areas where there is plenty of sunlight.*

Berry are different (rounder), but the similarity makes me think this plant could be of the [***prunus genus***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus). It could be a cultivar derived from pin cherries (*Prunus Pensylvanica*): it grows in cold US climate, so it usually is tricked to believe spring is here when GB winter is not cool enough...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Cornelian cherry, probably [*Cornus mas*](http://www.mortonarb.org/trees-plants/tree-plant-descriptions/cornelian-cherry-dogwood) given the location, although the time of year is off (fruit ripens at the end of July, not May).